# Async Method calls for loading Treeview for .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, treeview

I've read a number of replies on this website and looked through Microsoft documentation and some Youtube videos.  But I still don't get how Asynchronous methods works.  In most examples they return an int or something.  But that's not how I want to use them.  I have a Treeview and I'm loading the contents of Windows Explorer into it.  It's a slow process and I've implemented a kind of "Just in Time" load but it stills takes to long to load.

I initialize the tree with the TopNode (My PC) , then add the Drives below that.  Then the first level of folders below the drive letters e.g  Windows , Users, Program Files etc.  The rest of the sub-folders are only added for each folder if the users clicks on it.  This is to speed up the loading of the Treeview.  However, this is still to slow for some of the larger folder.

What I want to do is process each folder under the drive at the same time.  To reduce the user wait time.
Here is my code;

```
public static async void InitializeTreeView()
..
..
..
            foreach (DriveInfo d in MyDrives)
            {
                CustNode c = new CustNode();
                c.Name = d.Name;
                c.Text = d.Name;
                c.SelectedImageIndex = 3;
                c.ImageIndex = 3;
                c.NodeType = "Drive";
                Tview.TopNode.Nodes.Add(c);
                Tview.HideCheckBox(c);
                AddNodeToTree(c, c.Name, TreeViewDepth);
            }
```

The AddNodeToTree contains a recursive sub-folder call that uses the folder name to drill down into all subfolders and files.

Rather than waiting on this to finish I would like to run the foreach statement for each folder at the same time to speed up the process.

How can I do this ?

Erick

Comment: There is a simple rule: When you say **async** you have to say **await** too. Without any **await** the **async** is useless

Comment: BTW The main reason for async/await is to reduce **blocking**. It may take longer but with a smoother experience :o)

Comment: I think that this question is more related to *parallel-processing* than to *asynchronous*.

Comment: I agree with Theodor, i'm actually talking about parallel processing.  There is no point in displaying the tree view while the nodes are still being created. So I don't care if the screen is waiting.  I just want to process as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel or not, if the operation involves I/O, it should not be using parallel processing. Because any I/O operations has to be considered blocking by default.

Therefore any processes involve I/O are better to be done asynchronously.

The complete explanation of C# async usage preference is documented in: [Official doc of C# async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4040024)